# multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, query

I have 3 tables: `table_a` needs to communicate with `table_c`, but has to go to `table_b` first. Or put differently: `table_a` refers to `table_b` which then refers to `table_c`.

The relationship between the tables is defined as:

- `table_a.licno` relates to `table_b.licno`
- `table_b.ID` relates to `table_c.ID`

I need to retrieve 3 columns from `table_c` like the following:

- table_c.lastname
- table_c.firstname
- table_c.middlename

Here's my code so far:

```
select firstname, middlename, lastname 
from table_c
where table_b.licno=table_a.licno 
and table_c.employeeid = table_b.employeeid;
```

I am receiving the following error message:

> multi-part identifier could not be bound

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide all tables DDLs and the query text.

Comment: Your `WHERE` references tables a & b, but those tables aren't `JOIN`ed in your main query.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm unfamiliar with the INNER JOIN function, can you help me out how do I do that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's as simple as adding the tables you are joining to the `FROM` part of your query.

```
select    firstname,
          middlename,
          lastname 
from      table_c, 
          table_b, 
          table_a
where     table_b.licno      = table_a.licno 
and       table_c.employeeid = table_b.employeeid;
```

The statement can only join information from tables which are referenced in the `FROM` part of the `SELECT` statement.

You can also use the newer `JOIN` notation which might give you an idea why your statement didn't work the first time round:

```
SELECT      firstname,
            middlename,
            lastname 
FROM        table_c 
    JOIN    table_b 
        ON  table_c.employeeid = table_b.employeeid
    JOIN    table_a
        ON  table_b.licno = table_a.licno;
```

You can then go on to alias (give the tables a short name) the referenced tables, to shorten the statements:

```
SELECT      firstname,
            middlename,
            lastname 
FROM        table_c AS c
    JOIN    table_b AS b
        ON  c.employeeid = b.employeeid
    JOIN    table_a AS a
        ON  b.licno = a.licno;
```

The error message in the title of your question, stems from the fact that you are trying to reference objects in your `WHERE` clause, which aren't listed in the `FROM`.

> ```
> multi-part identifier could not be bound
> ```

A multi-part identifier is something like:

```
database_name.schema_name.table_name.column_name
```

In your statement the following bit is a multi-part identifier:

```
table_c.employeeid
  ^          ^
  |          +--------- column_name
  +-------------------- table_name
```

Some systems support even the addition of a `server_name`.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks very much, sorry for being late for reply it worked